# WIX - Executing a batch file during uninstall

Tags: batch-file, wix, action, uninstallation

I need to execute a batch file during uninstall. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my code which is still not working:

```
<CustomAction Id="Install" FileKey="test.bat" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncNoWait" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Uninstall" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please, don't do that! Find out what operations are performed in the batch file and see if it's possible to cover that the supported way.